# How to handle this in high concurrency in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, concurrency

I have some code like this:

```
class BargainLogSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = BargainLog
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...

        bargain_count = BargainLog.objects.filter(bargain_start_log=bargain_start_log).count()

        # calculate `bargain_money` according to current `bargain_count`
        bargain_money = calculate_bargain_money(bargain_count, ...)

        BargainLog.objects.create(bargain_start_log=bargain_start_log, bargain_money=bargain_money)

        ...
```

In case of high concurrency, I would get the same value of `bargain_count`, and then I would not get `bargain_money` as expected. So, it there any approach I can bundle the `count()` and `create()` in atom like what a thread lock does.

I have tried:

```
class BargainLogSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = BargainLog
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...

        bargain_logs = BargainLog.objects.filter(bargain_start_log=bargain_start_log).select_for_update()
        with transaction.atomic():
            bargain_count = bargain_logs.count()
            # calculate `bargain_money` according to current `bargain_count`
            bargain_money = calculate_bargain_money(bargain_count, ...)
            BargainLog.objects.create(bargain_start_log=bargain_start_log, bargain_money=bargain_money)

        ...
```

But, the problem still remains in high concurrency.

Comment: This is a complicated question, and I don't think you shared enough details to get an accurate answer.  Please update to include *exactly* how this code is being executed.  eg. are you in a view?  a background task?

Comment: Updated. It's in the serializer create method.

Comment: What does `calculate_bargain_money` do?  My solution would require executing this code as SQL (using the ORM)

Comment: If you absolutely can't execute this code as SQL, then the only other solution I can think of would be use **[table locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/explicit-locking.html)**, which your DB might not support

Comment: `calculate_bargain_money` is just a function that do some math calculation which is can not translated to `SQL`. I have read this post as you linked. And it said a well-design code barely need to perform `table locks`. Maybe I want to consider refactor it.